# How to make all custom fields as shared in docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

While working with DocuSign we received a request to make all the text fields as shared for both the signors.
In our organization, we used to create custom text fields through the metadata and use it in a document/template.
We are trying to make all the fields as shared for this document but it is not working.
For the custom fields like text fields, checkboxes, etc, we have a form fields table and there we used to set the properties in the HTML format.(e.g Height:"10", Width:"200")

Below are the properties which we have set to get the desired output but failed to achieve the same.
Properties:

1. Shared: "True"
2. SharedMetadata:"True"
3. RequireInitialOnSharedChange:"True"
4. RequireInitialOnSharedChangeMetadata: "True"

Can you please guide us as we are not able to make all the fields shared with all the signors?

Comment: do you try to set those properties in html? Please if you add more detail of your setup

Comment: Can you provide an API log from the DocuSign side (with any PII removed)? We'll need to see exactly where those parameters are being defined in your tag definition